# What are some good examples of double entendre beer names?

Tags: drinking

Basically looking for some examples of funny/ innuendo beer names for inspiration.

There are some great ones here: [Beer Brands: The Ultimate List of the 50 Funniest, Stupidest and Best Beer Names...In The World, Ever](http://www.findmeagift.co.uk/topics/ultimate-list-of-funny-beer-names).

Comment: Feral - Karma Citra

Answer (score 4):

1. "[Fucking Hell](https://www.fucking-hell.de/)" of course. "Hell" is German word for "pale" and Fucking is a [village in Austria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fucking,_Austria) (pronounced "foo-king").

[image: Fucking Hell]

2. There is a Belgian beer named "Mort subite" which means "Sudden death". It's not that bad though that your days are counted after you drink it - I have drunk it and i'm still alive :)

Comment: I'm confused, why's the second one a double entendre?

Comment: Mmmm, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

If you're an IPA fan, it seems that brewers are almost required to make some hops-related pun when naming their beer. Here's a small handful of ones I've had:

- [Alaskan Hopothermia](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/alaskan-hopothermia-double-ipa/186777/)
- [Big E Hoppy Ending](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/big-e-hoppy-ending/166747/)
- [Clown Shoes Hoppy Feet](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/clown-shoes-hoppy-feet-black-ipa/118178/)
- [Coronado Hoppy Daze](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/coronado-hoppy-daze-ipa/36388/)
- [Cricket Hill Hopnotic](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/cricket-hill-hopnotic-ipa/34129/)
- [Destihl Hoperation Overload](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/destihl-hoperation-overload/146204/)
- [SKA Modus Hoperandi IPA](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/ska-modus-hoperandi-ipa/99487/)

Comment: This question is probably going to get closed, but FWIW: Alpine Brewing: Pure Hoppiness.

Answer (score 1):

A Schwarzbier called "[Use The Schwarz](https://untappd.com/b/revolution-brewing-company-use-the-schwarzbier/228772)"

Answer (score 1):

[Flying Dog](http://flyingdogbrewery.com/) has Doggie Style Pale Ale, Pearl Necklace Chesapeake Stout, and Raging Bitch Belgian-Style IPA as examples of their more colorful beer names.